# JSP session variables set in a secure page 'https' are not accessible in a normal 'http' page

Tags: jsp

I am trying to login a user using a jsp over https and i am storing his userid and some more personal info in a session variable session.setAttribute("userid",98767)  when i move on to another non secure jsp ex: http://www/xyz.com/test.jsp and try to acces the session variable session.getAttribute("userid") i always get a null value, where as if i set the session variable in a normal http jsp i can access the variables properly.

Any help/pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine browsers assume cookies set via HTTPS shouldn't be transferred over HTTP, as they may be sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=197150), what you can do is create your session from an http page first, then switch to https. Can't tell you if it's correct or not though, just pointing it out.